# Plugin and Workflow activities are not updating in other Organizations of Dynamics CRM

Tags: dll, plugins, workflow, dynamics-crm-2016

I am moving a plugin (including its message) and custom workflow activities using a solution of Dynamics CRM V9.0 DEV (on-premise) organization to another on-premise organization. But none of them are getting in target organization.

Previously all the plugin and workflows was working fine in both organizations and we were using the same solution to move. We'd reset IIS, moving solution again and again but still the issue is same.

I want to know what could be reason behind for not updating Plugin and Custom workflow assemblies in target organization.

Comment: Are you not getting an error on solution import?

Comment: There is nothing like exception or error while importing solution

Comment: So the plug-ins already exist in the org you are importing into, but they are not being updated?  How do you know?

Comment: I've change logic for plugins in source organization where they are working fine

Comment: So you are testing the plugin within CRM to see if the dll has changed?  I'd suggest exporting the plugin dlls from both environments (source and target) and comparing them to prove that they are indeed not the same and maybe even decompile the target plugin to ensure that it isn't what you are expecting it to be.